# push_back() not working on more than one vector in one function...why?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm new to coding (and to Stack Overflow), learning about the basics of C++ right now. I want to write a simple program that:
A) collects days (strings) of a week
B) collects numbers (ints) that represent orders delivered during the week, and
C) prints out the day - order pairs.

I've been trying to use push_back() to do this, and it seems like whatever I do, push_back() works only on the first vector. Does anyone know why this is? Am I missing something fundamental about push_back()? Any help is greatly appreciated!^-^

The result of this code right now is a runtime error coming from the last part where I try to print the pairs. When you remove the orders vector from cout, the code works... This is why I think that the problem is that somehow push_back() doesn't work on the orders vector, and therefore its non-existent elements cannot be printed. What do you think?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;     

int main()
{

// collecting workdays:
// example input: Monday Tuesday Friday
cout << "Please enter the days you have worked on during this week:\n";

vector <string> days;

for (string s; cin >> s; ) 
    days.push_back(s);

// collecting orders delivered:
// example input: 11 12 10
cout << "Please enter the number of orders you delivered each day this week:\n";

vector <int> orders;

for (int x; cin >> x; )
    orders.push_back(x);

// printing day - order pairs
/* desired output based on the example input & output:
Monday = 11 orders
Tuesday = 12 orders
Friday = 10 orders */
for (int i = 0; i < days.size(); ++i)
    cout << days[i] << " = " << orders[i] << "orders\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not the `push_back()` that's not working, it's the input. That's why you're supposed to extract a [mcve] first, it could have nudged you in that direction. That said, "doesn't work" is not a useful description of a problem. You should describe what you observed, not just dump your (possibly flawed!) interpretation thereof. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

initialize the for-loops properly. their you didn't put any condition how much time the iteration will occurs.

```
for (string s; cin >> s; ) 
days.push_back(s);
```

push_back is working but every time it's wait for a new input in "cin >> s". 1st and 2nd for-loop have the same problem

Comment: thank you very much for your help; I was wrong to assume that push_back was the problem, and now I finally understand why. I wish you a great day!

Answer (score 1):

```
for (string s; cin >> s; ) 
    days.push_back(s);
```

Keeps on reading new strings from stdin until the steam is exhausted (or some other error occurs), which doesn't happen, if you're getting the input from user input in the terminal.

Assuming you want space separated inputs of day names that terminate when the user presses <kbd>enter</kbd> you could read a line from `std::cin` and create a `std::istringstream` from the line read:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <utility>

...

std::string line; 
if (std::getline(std::cin, line)) // read just a single line
{
    std::istringstream ss(std::move(line)); // create a stream containing only the contents of the line read

    // parse every input from the line
    for (string s; ss >> s; )
    {
        days.push_back(s);
    }
}

...
```

The second loop has the same similar issue. Furthermore you could run into undefined behaviour, if the user enters more day names than integers.

---

You could of course use a different way of determining the end of the user input, e.g. by stopping after the first 7 strings/ints read.

Comment: thank you so much for your help, now my code works! To solve the problem you raised, I added a little test after collecting the days & orders to see if the numbers match, else there is an error message saying there's a discrepancy. I wish you a wonderful day!